# automatically generate names

Tags: community

i am working on a project please help,i am doing attendance management.i have Students and teacher object in salesforce,so to mark the attendance i'll goto teacher object,select the student name and select present in the particular class.i want those student who are not present in the class, Automatically Generate their names.Is it Possible?And separate attendance percentage for each student.so that we can remind them if they has less percentage.

Please Help!!!!!!I'll be very thankful to you all

Comment: Sounds like a cool project. What did you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

You can create report for this functionality. In the report you can apply filter that "Present is check". With the report you can get details of all students which are not present in the class.